# trying to build an image generator with open

Tags: node.js, openai-api, image-generation

i wonder why the result is false? Thanks in advance!

```
const OpenAI = require('openai');

const openai = new OpenAI({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY 
});

const generateImage = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await openai.images.generate({
      prompt: 'Polar bear on ice skates',
      n: 1,
      size: '1024x1024'
    });
    
    const imageUrl = response.data.data[0].url

    res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      data: imageUrl,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response) {
      console.log(error.response.status);
      console.log(error.response.data);
    } else {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
    res.status(400).json({
      success: false,
      error: 'The image could not be generated',
    });
  }
};

module.exports = { generateImage };
```

When i tried on postman, it shows:
{
"success": false,
"error": "The image could not be generated"
}

Comment: You can print the error to see what happens